I can`t pass data from View input field to ViewModel. WPF, Prism
I'm trying to add a new user to the database using the following command:
 <Button IsDefault="True" Content="Зберегти" Command="{Binding AddUserCommand}">

However, it seems that the ViewModel class isn't being invoked. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The namespace appears to be correct, and there are no binding errors shown in IntelliSense. I've tried debugging, but it seems the program doesn't even attempt to enter the constructor of the ViewModel class.
Here's my XAML view:
<Window x:Class="EmployeeDirectoryWPF.View.AddWindow" ...
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EmployeeDirectoryWPF.ViewModel" 
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:AddViewModel}"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
        ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"> 
       
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Ім'я:" />
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                 Text="{Binding  Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />    

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="10" Grid.Column="1" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20">
            <Button IsDefault="True" Content="Зберегти"
                    Command="{Binding AddUserCommand}" Margin="0,0,25,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

And here's my ViewModel class:
namespace EmployeeDirectoryWPF.ViewModel;

public class AddViewModel : BindableBase
{    
    private Employee _newEmployee;
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees;    

    public Employee NewEmployee
    {
        get => _newEmployee;
        set => SetProperty(ref _newEmployee, value);
    }

    private bool _isEnabled;
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return _isEnabled; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _isEnabled, value); }
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddUserCommand { get; private set; }

    public AddViewModel(ObservableCollection<Employee> employees, MyDbContext db)
    {
        _employees = employees;
        _newEmployee = new Employee();
        _db = db;

        AddUserCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddNewEmployee)
            .ObservesCanExecute(() => IsEnabled);
    }

    private void AddNewEmployee()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CanAddNewEmployee())
            {
                return;
            }

            _employees.Add(new Employee
            {
                Name = _newEmployee.Name,
                DateOfBirth = _newEmployee.DateOfBirth,                
            });

            _db.SaveChanges();

            NewEmployee = new Employee();
        }       
    } 

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thanks in advance!

How do you create the window?

You window makes a binding with your context only in designer according to d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:AddViewModel}". While I know prism does (depending on version) too much background magic, you still need to connect your ViewModel with the View (in your case window).  One way is in your MainWindow.xaml.cs in ctor set DataContext = new AddViewModel()

Is this a dialog?  Or is it a view you navigate to?  In Prism, you register view-models along with their views and then use Prism to navigate to them.  It's Prism's job to set the AddViewModel as the DataContext of the AddView.  If you've done things right, it will.  So I assume that somewhere you registered AddWindow with AddViewModel, right?  Somewhere you must have a line that registers them roughly like this, yes?  reg.RegisterForNavigation<AddWindow, AddViewModel>("Add");
